# Wrong solution to a quadratic equation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm facing a mathematical/programming problem which I don't really understand. In the following `α,β,θc` are given parameters, `ϕ` is the variable. I have to solve the equation `Cp=0`, where:

[image]

and:

[image]

The solutions that I have computed are:

[image]

Coding the above solutions with Python/Numpy, I find that:

- If `β=0`, then both solutions are correct: `Cp(ϕ1)=Cp(ϕ2)=0`.
- However, if `β!=0` then `Cp(ϕ1)!=0` (which is wrong) and `Cp(ϕ2)=0`. Why? I checked again and again the signs and terms on my coded expressions, they seem fine to me...

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
theta_c = np.deg2rad(10)
alpha = np.deg2rad([1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85])
beta = np.deg2rad(15)

lamb = np.cos(alpha) * np.cos(beta)
nu = -np.sin(beta)
omega = np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(beta)

common_1 = lamb * nu * np.tan(theta_c)
common_2 = omega * np.sqrt(omega**2 + nu**2 - lamb**2 * np.tan(theta_c)**2)
common_3 = omega**2 + nu**2

phi_1 = np.arcsin((-common_1 + common_2) / common_3)
phi_2 = np.arcsin((-common_1 - common_2) / common_3)

Cp = lambda phi: lamb * np.sin(theta_c) + nu * np.cos(theta_c) * np.sin(phi) - omega * np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta_c)

print(Cp(phi_1))
# OUTPUT: this is wrong!
# [-0.02357418 -0.04432021 -0.0779439  -0.10278244 -0.12111675 -0.13494261
#  -0.1457658  -0.15858164 -0.17562354 -0.19112922 -0.20703468 -0.22411243
#  -0.24265822 -0.26274848 -0.28434621 -0.3073487  -0.33161092 -0.35695785
#  -0.38319138 -0.41009444 -0.43743318 -0.4649581 ]

print(Cp(phi_2))
# OUTPUT: all values are very close to zero. Good solution.
# [-1.04083409e-17 -4.16333634e-17  0.00000000e+00 -1.38777878e-17
#  -2.77555756e-17 -2.77555756e-17  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
#   5.55111512e-17 -1.11022302e-16  1.11022302e-16  5.55111512e-17
#  -1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00 -3.88578059e-16 -1.11022302e-16
#  -2.77555756e-16  1.66533454e-16  5.55111512e-17  2.22044605e-16
#   5.55111512e-17 -2.22044605e-16]
```

Alternatively, I could use `fsolve` from Scipy optimize, which I have already verified it computes the correct solutions. However, this procedure will be executed many times by another iterative algorithm, so I'd rather use the analytical solutions.

Comment: Spicy question, I could take a more thorough look later. Just a quick heads-up: is your C_p lambda incorrect?  It's missing a 2, no?

Comment: Ohhh yes, let me clarify: the coded `Cp` is different from the formula. If `Cp=0` then the term inside the parentheses must be zero. That's why my coded `Cp` is only looking at that term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your analytical solution has a mistake.

I rewrote the target function in form

```
Cp(ϕ) = 2 * (A + B sin ϕ - C cos ϕ)^2
```

Solutions of `Cp = 0` come from `A + B sin ϕ - C cos ϕ = 0` equation, which I solved using [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) (WS). The solutions `ϕ₁`, `ϕ₂` I found are

```
# t is parameter in WS

            -B ± sqrt(B^2 - (A^2 - C^2))
t₁ and t₂ = ----------------------------
                      A + C

ϕ₁ = 2atan(t₁)
ϕ₂ = 2atan(t₂)
```

Here is code snippet written in Julia

```
using Plots

θ = deg2rad(10)
α = deg2rad(10)
β = deg2rad(15)

λ = cos(α) * cos(β)
ν = -sin(β)
ω = sin(α) * cos(β)

# Cp = 2 * (A + B sin ϕ - C cos ϕ)^2
A = λ * sin(θ)
B = ν * cos(θ)
C = ω * cos(θ)

t₁ = (-B + sqrt(B^2 - (A^2 - C^2)))/(A + C)
t₂ = (-B - sqrt(B^2 - (A^2 - C^2)))/(A + C)

ϕ₁ = 2atan(t₁)
ϕ₂ = 2atan(t₂)

Cfunc(ϕ) = 2*(A + B * sin(ϕ) - C * cos(ϕ))^2

plot(Cfunc; xlims=(-10, 10), label="Cₚ")
scatter!([ϕ₁, ϕ₂], Cfunc.([ϕ₁, ϕ₂]); label="Solutions")
```

producing

[image]

I played with value of `β`, seems like the code above works good for both zero and non-zero degrees. Also, I didn't care about function domains, you should reproduce the derivation to ensure that all parameters and solution are well-defined.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your solution is spot on. I tested it on my code and it provides the correct answer for different values of beta. Interesting to note that my original solutions were exactly the same as the one reported in a NASA paper.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. @Davide_sd, could you enlighten me, which field of study did you face this equation?

Comment: Sure: hypersonic aerothermodynamics. The paper is "Tables of aerodynamic coefficients obtained from developed newtonian expressions for complete and partial conic and spheric bodies at combined angle of attack and sideslip with some comparison with hypersonic experimental data", by William R. Wells and William O. Armstrong, 1962